# MVVM Light Messenger doesn't work

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

ViewModelA:

inside its constructor (breakpoint hits the foll. line):

```
Messenger.Default.Register<int>(this, "token", OnHitIt);
```

ViewModelB:

breakpoint does hit this line:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(hitItId, "token")
```

But for some reason breakpoint never hits OnHitIt method, what could be the reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

On ViewModelA:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<int>>(this, OnHitIt);
```

And the OnHitIt method would be-

```
private void OnHitIt(NotificationMessage<int> m)
{
    if (m.Notification == "token")
    {
        // code goes here
        // m.Content will get the int passed in
    }
}
```

On ViewModelB:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<int>(hitItId, "token"));
```

Comment: I guess it should have worked my way too, but as you told do this way. By doing that I learnt that it was type mismatch. int and int?. BTW, i'm new to c# whats the difference? any link would help

Comment: confirmed, it wasn't working because it was type mismatch between for int and int? and wasnt giving any error. Now my old code works too.

Comment: int? means that the value can hold an integer or null, where as int can only hold an integer

Answer (score 0):

One reason would be that ViewModelA is no longer referenced by anything, but more likely it's that token look-up is is by reference and not by value.  In other words "token" in the Register is not the same reference as "token" in the Send.

Comment: No ViewModelA is the MainViewModel so can't be out of reference (kind of parent view model). How can be "token" different from "token" I am passing hardcoded value.

Comment: Question was answered but just for reference, token can be simple value or reference type. If one uses reference type, then reference is tested. If value type, value is tested. For strings, the value is tested.